# defaults "command not found" when executed after declaration of variable

Tags: macos, bash, unix

Why does the following code not work?

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=$PWD/Info
defaults read $PATH
```

Everytime I execute it I get

> ./script: line 3: defaults: command not found

Once I do it in one line it work

```
defaults read $PWD/Info
```

It's ok like that. I'm just curious.

Comment: Variables are case sensitive. By convention, all-caps variables are globals or environment variables. You should use lowercase names for your script-local variables. It's also worth learning about the more important ones among these globals, like PATH.

Comment: @mkaito: there are no custom variables in Hedge code. PATH and PWD must be uppercased to get their special meaning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are changing `$PATH`, which is a special variable. The shell uses PATH for searching executable programs. `defaults` is probably one of them, but after removing its folder from PATH, the shell cannot execute it anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Add to the path instead of replacing it:

```
PATH=$PWD/Info:$PATH
```

Comment: Should be: `PATH="$PWD/Info:$PATH"` or `PATH="$PATH:$PWD/Info"`

Comment: @jlliagre: The quotes aren't necessary. Word splitting isn't performed on the right side of an assignment. The only time you would need quotes is if you're including special characters literally.

Comment: Indeed, my points were more the separator (you used a semicolon instead of a colon, fixed now by grawity) and the path component order. Unless commands are specifically designed to take precedence over standard one, I prefer the extra components to be appended, not prepended, for obvious security reasons.